# Does LUKS' luksAddKey have a problem with passwords being exactly 64 characters long?

Tags: password, luks, cryptsetup

```
Ubuntu: 20.04.3 LTS
LUKS Version: 1
Cipher name: aes
Cipher mode: xts-plain64
Hash spec: sha256
```

I noticed some weird behaviour when using luksAddKey, when the password is exactly 64 characters long. I can't believe that is a bug, so i would like to know, what i'm missing.

The first input of the new password has a length of 64 characters. The second input (=verification) is the first password without its last character, so it has a length of 63 characters. Example:

aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

```
# cryptsetup --pbkdf-force-iterations 1000 luksAddKey $DEVICE
Enter any existing passphrase: 
Enter new passphrase for key slot:     <- 64 characters
Verify passphrase:                     <- 63 characters
#
```

Despite the inputs being different, a new slot has been configured. I can clear the slot with any of the 2 inputs, as if they were the same. Instead i would expect an error message for one of the passwords.

```
# cryptsetup luksRemoveKey $DEVICE
Enter passphrase to be deleted: 
#
```

The character count limit shouldn't cause this, because this is much higher (512):

```
# cryptsetup --help | tail -n14

Default compiled-in metadata format is LUKS2 (for luksFormat action).

Default compiled-in key and passphrase parameters:
    Maximum keyfile size: 8192kB, Maximum interactive passphrase length 512 (characters)
Default PBKDF for LUKS1: pbkdf2, iteration time: 2000 (ms)
Default PBKDF for LUKS2: argon2i
    Iteration time: 2000, Memory required: 1048576kB, Parallel threads: 4

Default compiled-in device cipher parameters:
    loop-AES: aes, Key 256 bits
    plain: aes-cbc-essiv:sha256, Key: 256 bits, Password hashing: ripemd160
    LUKS: aes-xts-plain64, Key: 256 bits, LUKS header hashing: sha256, RNG: /dev/urandom
    LUKS: Default keysize with XTS mode (two internal keys) will be doubled.
```

Can anyone else confirm this behaviour?